# How to disable vibration on widget drop?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-touchwiz, drag-n-drop

*Samsung Galaxy Ace 2.*

I set vibration to activate only in silent mode. I am **not** in silent mode, and yet when I drag and drop a widget from desktop to desktop, or to trash, on each drop phone vibrates.

How to stop it, i.e. how to disable this kind of vibration?

Comment: This seems to be a little bit on the picky side when it comes to UI.  Barring any kind of physical sense disorder of course.

Answer (score 5):

The vibration you are referring to it's called "Haptic feedback", and can be disabled for certain UI interactions. This may or may not work for you:

1. Touch "home";
2. Touch "menu";
3. Touch "Settings";
4. Touch "Sound";
5. Scroll your way to "Haptic Feedback";
6. Disable it by touching to remove the green tick.

Try and see if it provides the desired effect. Take not that this option doesn't affect all UI interactions, as mentioned under that option.

Comment: It looks promising thank you, but I don't have this option "haptic feedback". Anywhere (however I could miss something, the settings are scattered around this phone, and I am having problems finding some of them).